# How to Upload/Download Folder on skyDrive in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I am working on SkyDrive API. I'm able to upload/download files & rename files. But what I need is to upload Folders onto SkyDrive & download folders from SkyDrive.

I searched but could not find anything for folder downloading/uploading. Is there any way to upload/download folders from SkyDrive?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this direct from the SkyDrive SDK, you would need to iterate over the file list within a folder to create a nested array and then have your code do this yourself. You can alternatively look at the [SMEStorage multi-cloud API](http://smestorage.com/?p=static&page=for_developers) which have an API that supports skydrive also and which appears to support folder download